# Angular (Chrome) OnBeforeUnload / Unload event doesn't hear closing tab, but refresh is ok

Tags: angular, google-chrome, onbeforeunload

Need some help with detecting closing tab/browser.
I Have WebSocketService, who lock some type of objects and tell about it to other users.

When ws succefully connected I have to add window event listener:

```
const unload = (e: BeforeUnloadEvent) => {
  // if no locked objects - return
  if (!this.lockedObjects?.length) return;
  console.info('WebSocketService -> Window: onbeforeunload()');
  this.unlockAll();
  // first parts of browsers need this option
  e.preventDefault();
  // second type need this
  e.returnValue = 'test';
}
window.onbeforeunload = unload;
window.addEventListener('unload', unload);
```

while F5/Ctrl + F5 - i saw preventing closing, but when click for close tab - no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem was with **return**

worked code below:

```
window.onbeforeunload = (e: BeforeUnloadEvent) => {
      e.preventDefault(); // for first type of browsers
      return e.returnValue = 'test'; // for second type of browsers
    };
```